# Java Reflection isArray() always false

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I got a question about Java Reflections: I have to checkout, if a certain field of a class is an array.
But my problem is: If i run isArray() on the attribute of the class directly, it works. But if I use it in the way below, it won"t work. I guess because the "real" array is in this Field class?
Any idea how i get it to work - I think there is missing a cast or sth like that?
Thanks!

```
Field fields[] = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getClass().isArray()) {
        //Always false.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`field.getType()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType())!

Answer (score 4):

Your code should read

```
Field fields[] = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for(Field field : fields) {
  if(field.getType().isArray()){
     //Actually works
  }
}
```

Using field.getClass() as you are will always return Field.class or a Class instance of a subclass of Field*.

*My apologizes for such a confusingly worded sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the individual elements of Fields, rather than the array itself.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this at all.  "Elements of Fields?"  Arrays have elements.  Fields don't.

Comment: 'fields' as in the variable 'fields'.